# Java Regular Expression : Need Simpler Solution

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am new to regular expressions. I have a string named `encryptId` (does not contain `|`) and I want to append the `|` character after every 20 characters of this string, using the `encryptId.replace/replaceAll(Regex,Pattern)` function in Java. But it should never have `\` at the end of the string.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

1. The reason I want to use `replace` and `replaceAll` functions particularly is because I have to use that in **[velocity template mananger](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html)**. And there we can use common String functions but can't write whole java code.
2. My current solution is shown below

> ```
> encryptId = encryptId.replaceAll("(.{20})","$1|");
> if(encryptId.charAt(encryptId.length() - 1)=='|') {
>     encryptId = encryptId.substring(0,encryptId.length()-1);
> }
> ```

I need to get rid of this `if` statement so that It would be just a string function.

Comment: Why do you want to use `replace` or `replaceAll` particularly? I think it'd be much easier to do using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: you need a simpler solution? show us your current solution.

Comment: @PhilippSander , I specify that solution in EDIT.

Comment: @ArunBhati What is the problem with the second part? Is the problem that you can't use substring or that you can't use charAt?

Comment: @PaulBoddington, It's just that I think from regular expression itself we can remove if statement.

Comment: @ArunBhati I don't know about regex I'm afraid. To be honest, this question is too old to get many views now. If I were you I'd accept one of the two answers below (they did answer your original question), and ask this question with more restrictions as a new question.

Comment: @Pirate_Jack We can do this via regex itself. We only need a lookahead. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via regular expressions as follows

```
static String enterADelimiter(String str, String delimiter, int after) {
        String regex = "(.{" + after +"})(?!$)";
        String replacement = "$1" + delimiter;

        return str.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
    }
```

Just use

```
enterADelimiter(yourString, "|", 20)
```

This will return correct solution. Explantion

```
(            Start group 1
  .          Match Anything
  {after}    after times
)            End group 1
(?!$)        Don't match if at end of String
```

Comment: Thanks @Aseem It worked. I upvoted your answer but It's not visible.

Comment: @Pirate_Jack Try again. Might work this time :D. You can accept the answer if it worked. The tick mark.

Comment: Ohh! It will be visible later as I don't have enough reputation so It will not be shown untill I get enough.

Comment: @Pirate_Jack I had completely forgotten that there was that limitation. But you should be able to accept it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 for how to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.toCharArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29):

```
    String s = "..."; //your string
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder("");
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
        res.append(c);
        i++;
        if (i % 20 == 0 && i != s.length()){
            res.append("|");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(res.toString());
```

`res` will have your first `String` with an `|` every 20 characters but not at the end of the `String`.

Comment: Note that you want to avoid concatenating strings in loops, since it creates intermediate strings. It is more efficient to append the characters to a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I was not sure if the compiler would optimize this and use StringBuilders under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to do it with `replaceAll`: I say don't. Regular expressions are not always the best approach to string manipulation problems.

You can efficiently build the new string by taking 20 character blocks from `encryptId` and appending them to a `StringBuilder`, optionally appending the pipe if it will not be at the end of the string:

```
String method(String encryptId) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(encryptId.length() + encryptId.length() / 20);
  for (int i = 0; i < encryptId.length(); i += 20) {
    int end = Math.min(i + 20, encryptId.length());
    sb.append(encryptId, i, end);
    if (end != encryptId.length()) {
      sb.append('|');
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, and after correcting the typos, `|` can be at the end of the string.

Comment: @PaulBoddington fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted since this is the most efficient solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Regex may complicate things more. You can also try to use `StringBuilder` for this:

```
        String encryptId = "test";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(encryptId);

        int insertAfter = 20;
        for(int i = encryptId.length(); i > 0 ; i--) {
            if (i % insertAfter == 0 && i != encryptId.length()) {
                builder.insert(i, "|");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note that inserting a character in the middle of a `StringBuilder` is quadratic, since it involves shifting up all of the following characters. [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.insert%28int%2Cchar%29)